# jConsole Verbose Output

Tags: java, jconsole

I'm looking for resources that explains how to read and debug jconsole verbose output. I've searched extensively in google and stackoverflow but I can't find anything. Maybe I'm searching with incorrect keywords. The jConsole output looks something like below. I've modified any identifying elements as it's an enterprise application.

```
********* 2018-05-01 17:08:43 Duration: 00:05:37 *********
    ---------- SCRIPT CALLS ----------
         TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
      millisec    microsec    microsec    microsec
       231,586  33,083,715  47,981,604     167,813          7  abc.text.script1
       231,420  38,570,150  47,982,065   6,511,646          6  abc.text.script2
       231,418  38,569,707  47,981,612   6,511,188          6  abc.text.script3
       231,418  38,569,672  47,981,574   6,511,158          6  abc.text.script4
       200,229  33,371,556  41,666,686   4,918,866          6  abc.text.script5
       200,229  33,371,541  41,666,672   4,918,853          6  abc.text.script6

        -----------------------------------------------------
     2,146,587       1,714  47,982,065           0  1,835,704


     ********* 2018-05-01 17:08:43 Duration: 00:05:37 *********
    ---------- SCRIPT CALL STACKS ----------
         TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
      millisec    microsec    microsec    microsec
       231,420  38,570,150  47,982,065   6,511,646          6  abc.text.script1
       231,418  38,569,707  47,981,612   6,511,188          6  . abc.text.sub-script1
       231,418  38,569,699  47,981,604   6,511,180          6  . . abc.text.sub-script2
       231,418  38,569,672  47,981,574   6,511,158          6  . . . abc.text.sub-script3
       200,229  33,371,556  41,666,686   4,918,866          6  . . . . abc.text.sub-script4
       200,229  33,371,541  41,666,672   4,918,853          6  . . . . . abc.text.sub-script5

        -----------------------------------------------------
       277,359      60,334  47,982,065           0      4,597


     ********* 2018-05-01 17:08:43 Duration: 00:05:37 *********
    ---------- SCRIPT COMPILATIONS ----------
         TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
      millisec    microsec    microsec    microsec
             3       3,907       3,907       3,907          1  script1
             3       3,086       3,086       3,086          1  script2
             2       2,842       2,842       2,842          1  script3
             2       2,412       2,412       2,412          1  script4
             2       2,360       2,360       2,360          1  script5

        -----------------------------------------------------
            81       1,543       3,907         632         53


     ********* 2018-05-01 17:08:43 Duration: 00:05:37 *********
    ---------- DATABASE OPERATIONS ----------
         TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
      millisec    microsec    microsec    microsec
        48,417         616     118,736         382     78,482  Query1
         9,755       3,648      46,376         727      2,674  Query2

        -----------------------------------------------------
       111,447         838     837,754         234    132,939


     ********* 2018-05-01 17:08:43 Duration: 00:05:37 *********
    ---------- INTERFACE OPERATIONS ----------
         TOTAL     AVERAGE     LONGEST    SHORTEST      COUNT  ELEMENT
      millisec    microsec    microsec    microsec
       231,562  38,593,789  47,989,713   6,533,846          6  Interface1
        27,785   3,473,194   5,401,932       4,735          8  Interface2

        -----------------------------------------------------
       272,055   4,611,112  47,989,713       4,735         59
```